# Type mismatch expression

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

Here is the code I tried to execute but error:

```
string g = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
string h = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

//string sql2 = @"select Loanno,PName,Duedate,sum(Rec) as rec,sum(Loanamt) as amt from Due where Duedate between [@date1] and [@date2] group by PName order by Loanno asc";

string sql2 = @"select Due.Loanno,Due.PName,Due.Duedate,sum(Due.Rec) as rec,sum(Due.Loanamt) as amt from Due  inner join Party_Det on Due.Loanno=Party_Det.Loanno where Due.Duedate between [@date1] and [@date2] group by Due.Loanno,Due.PName,Due.Duedate";

OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(sql2, con);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", g);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", h);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

DataTable dt=new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd2);
da.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
con.Close();
```

Comment: Add your complete error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
string sql2 = @"select Due.Loanno, Due.PName, Due.Duedate, sum(Due.Rec) as rec,sum(Due.Loanamt) as amt from Due  inner join Party_Det on Due.Loanno=Party_Det.Loanno where Due.Duedate between @date1 and @date2 group by Due.Loanno,Due.PName,Due.Duedate";
OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(sql2, con);

cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", dateTimePicker1.Value.Date);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", dateTimePicker2.Value.Date);

cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd2);

da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
con.Close();
```

**ADDED :** Why do you need the join with `Party_det` table? You are not using any fields from that table.. Make sure that the `Loanno` column in both tables are of same data type.

Comment: Problem not in date format but query plz help but in query

Comment: System.Data.Oledb.OleDbException: Type mismatch in Expression

Comment: Try the updated answer... You were using passing `String` value in place of `Date`

Comment: Run the query in MS Access and see what it says. I doubt it's something other than due date... Check the type of `Rec` and `Loanamt` columns and make sure they are numbers as you are calculating the sum of those fields..

Comment: yes ji i checked. problem is not in date but in query

Comment: Why do you need the join with `Party_det` table? You are not using any fields from that table.., is the `Loanno` in both tables are of same data type?

Comment: @vigneshVerWisH see, simple things we overlook are always going to be the worst nightmare... :-)

Comment: I have an another Problem date form ji